# Problema con usar una función de un controlador de Symfony en otra app hecha en php ubicada en web

Tags: php, symfony

por favor si alguien me puede ayuda con lo siguiente , necesito usar una función de un controlador que esta en una app en Symfony en un archivo php que no esta usando Symfony y solo utiliza php  sin symphony, existe alguna forma que yo pueda usar esta función del controlador en otro archivo php que esta almacenada en web .

```
Ruta de mi controlador

facturas 
       src 
          factelbundle
                 controller
                      controladorquetienemifuncion.php

ruta del archivo en donde quiero usar mi la funcion del controlador

facturas 
       web 
          webservice
                consume
                     documentoquequierousarlafunciondelcontrolador.php
```

por favor si alguien me puede decir si puede unir estas y si pueda usar la función o si me puede ayudar con otra solución estaría muy agradecido

Comment: creo la funcionalidad deberías hacerla como servicio, y así la empleas en el controlador o fuera del mismo.

Comment: Hola @Francisco gracias por responder el problema es que es una función demasiado larga y replicarla en un servicio seria muy extensa .